# Python - Convert Array of Float audio data to wav file

Tags: python, numpy, wav, numpy-ndarray, waveform

I have audio data recorded from microphone like this : (ndarray of float)

```
> print(data)
[-0.00762939 -0.00817871 -0.00714111 ...  0.0265511   0.02484207   0.02377392]
```

This is my code:

```
while(recording):
   frames.append(data)

waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME + "_" + str(COUNT_FILE) + ".wav", 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.wr(b''.join(frames))
waveFile.close()
```

But when I play the audio it become broken, nothing but just noise... how to convert it into .wav audio file?

Comment: waveFile.wr(b''.join(frames)) --> wrong syntax,
correction :
waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))

Comment: You can edit your question.

Comment: Please add the library import statements: I don't know how you're creating these wav's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use pack your data first using struct

replace your waveFile.writeframeswith this

```
data=struct.pack( 'h' * len(frames), *frames )
waveFile.writeframes(data)
```

and maybe also convert your data to integers since I think wav files uses only integers values

Comment: Thanks now I can produce better wav audio, but still using float and I still get noise. I don't know why when using integer it just turning into empty voice.

Comment: **SOLVED**
I must multiply the audio data by 1000 or 10000 because the numpy array are float number below 1

Comment: it is most probably normalized value, it is better to know the normalization factor and multiply your array with it

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the scipy library. It is much easier to work with than the wave module:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wf
RATE = 44100
... your code that puts an array of floats into data ...

wf.write('test.wav', RATE, data)
```

If you send wavfile.write numpy float32 values it assumes they are in the range -1 to 1.